# fpdf com cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Estou usando a biblioteca no cakephp de fpdp, criei um método privado no meu controller montando um pdf básico e depois chamei esse método em uma action mas ele não gera o pdf..

método privado:

```
private function montaPDF(){
    require('fdpf/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    $pdf->Output();
}
```

e retorna esse erro na minha page:

> %PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r Q�w3T04�30PISp  �Z*�[����(hx����+���(j*�d��7W endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 5 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.7) /CreationDate (D:20150824102520) >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f 0000000228 00000 n 0000000416 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000315 00000 n 0000000520 00000 n 0000000595 00000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 644 %%EOF

Comment: Você já verificou se ele não esta renderizando a view? tenta `$this->autoRender = false`

Comment: sim, está com autoRender = false;

Answer (score 0):

1 - Crie um layout por exemplo "pdf.ctp" em /views/layoyts

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

2 - No controlador, use o layout citado acima.

3 - Na visão, certifique-se de usar o TCPDF com a codificação correta.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Link: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a134232ae3ad1ec186ed45046f94b7755